# Postgresql 9.6 parallel execution don't work

Tags: postgresql, parallel-processing

I installed a Postgresql 9.6 on an Ubuntu 16.04 Server and did the same steps as in this blog:

http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql96-parallel-sequential-scan/

1. set max_parallel_workers_per_gather to 8
2. `CREATE TABLE test (i int);`
3. `INSERT INTO test SELECT generate_series(1,100000000);`
4. `ANALYSE test;`

But there is no parallelization, neither in the execution plan nor visible with htop.

Is there something else to care of to activate parallelization?

**Edit**
Queries I tried:

1. `SELECT * FROM test;`
2. `SELECT * FROM test WHERE i=1;`
3. `SELECT * FROM test WHERE i<90000000;`
4. `SELECT count(*) from test;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found another configuration value which isnt mentioned on all sites i digged.

After changing `max_worker_processes` also to 8 everything worked.

Comment: For the record, both parameters are in the docs here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/how-parallel-query-works.html